# How to print multidimensinal array dynamically until count

Tags: php, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

I have a `JSON` value which I am getting from db below

```
[{"skill_title":["developer","jQuery","HTML"],"skill_marks":["50%","100%","80%"]}]
```

I am decoding this value like this below

```
$usrskill = json_decode($usrskill[0]->skills,true);
```

and, I got the following result:

```
    Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [skill_title] => Array
                (
                    [0] => developer
                    [1] => jQuery
                    [2] => HTML
                )

            [skill_marks] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 50%
                    [1] => 100%
                    [2] => 80%
                )

        )

)
```

All I want is to assign the all data to input field value dynamically like I have two input fields

```
<div>
    <input placeholder="Engineer,Doctor,Developer etc." type="text" name="skills[]" value="">
    <input placeholder="Eg. 80%" type="text" name="skillmark[]" value="">
</div>
```

I want to load this input fields until values are coming in this result

**EXPECTED RESULT** This is what I want hope I am able to tell you what I want

```
<div>
    <input type="text" name="skills[]" value="developer">
    <input type="text" name="skillmark[]" value="50%">
</div>


<div>
    <input type="text" name="skills[]" value="jQuery">
    <input type="text" name="skillmark[]" value="100%">
</div>

<div>
    <input type="text" name="skills[]" value="HTML">
    <input type="text" name="skillmark[]" value="80%">
</div>
```

I am using `foreach` loop for this, but it is getting static data not dynamic

```
foreach ($usrskill as $key => $value) {
    echo $value['skill_title'][0] .' Marks '. $value['skill_marks'][0];
}
```

Comment: please paste your current code as well which is not working?

Comment: actually i am using foreach loop but it only get the static data

Comment: still we can not help you as there is no scope of what exactly you have written..

Comment: @SixthSense i have updated my question please check

Comment: just see the expected result and that will understand what i want

Comment: How [0] will work here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have your array $usrskill that is an array of one element, this is because of your JSON. So you can take this element, that is what you want.
Then you can look over you arrays.

```
The json is an array with one object inside.
$json = '[{"skill_title":["developer","jQuery","HTML"],"skill_marks":["50%","100%","80%"]}]';
//Decode json...
$usrskill = json_decode($json, true);
//... And get the first and only element inside.
$usrskill = $usrskill[0];
//Your two arrays have to have the same length!
$count = count($usrskill["skill_title"]);
//Look over every element and echo the html you want.
for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
    echo '
    <div>
        <input type="text" name="skills[]" value="' . $usrskill['skill_title'][$i] . '">
        <input type="text" name="skillmark[]" value="' . $usrskill['skill_marks'][$i] . '">
     </div>
    ';
}
```

Here you can see [LIVE DEMO](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/9d15612aceb2afff5c6a2f8822154aaec942f2df) (Thanks to [@Faisal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3185734/faisal))

Comment: This is the error i am getting `Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array`

Comment: According to you var_dump, you have an array. What line is failing ? With no more code, I can not test deeply.

Comment: I've updated the code, and added json decode. I tested it, it works for me.

Comment: Thanks it is working fine actually i don't know how to make foreach dynamic thanks mate

Comment: The problem was at the beginning, inside json_decode I think. Then I just look over array with a counter, because I need to iterate through two arrays.

Answer (score 1):

This will work with the JSON array given.

```
   <?php

    $json = '[{"skill_title":["developer","jQuery","HTML"],"skill_marks":["50%","100%","80%"]}]';

    $jsonArray = json_decode($json, true);

    $html = '<div>';

    foreach($jsonArray[0]['skill_title'] as $k=>$v) {

        $html .= '<input type="text" name="skills[]" value="' . $v . '">';
        $html .= '<input type="text" name="skillmark[]" value="' . $jsonArray[0]['skill_marks'][$k] . '">';
        $html .= '</div>';

    }

    echo $html;

    ?>
```

**Output**

```
<div><input type="text" name="skills[]" value="developer"><input type="text" name="skillmark[]" value="50%"></div>

<input type="text" name="skills[]" value="jQuery"><input type="text" name="skillmark[]" value="100%"></div>

<input type="text" name="skills[]" value="HTML"><input type="text" name="skillmark[]" value="80%"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use another foreach loop:
Try below instead:

```
foreach ($usrskill as $key => $value) {
    $count = 0;
    foreach($value['skill_title'] as $tital){
        echo $value['skill_title'][$count] .' Marks '. $value['skill_marks'][$count];
        $count++;
    }
}
```

Hope this will help :)

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work in your above case-

```
<?php

$test = '[{"skill_title":["developer","jQuery","HTML"],"skill_marks":["50%","100%","80%"]}]';

$usrskill = json_decode($test,true); 

foreach($usrskill as $kk=> $test){ 

    foreach($test['skill_title'] as $kk=> $test1){
        echo '<div>
    <input type="text" name="skills[]" value="'.$test1.'">
    <input type="text" name="skillmark[]" value="'.$test['skill_marks'][$kk].'">
</div>';
    }
}
```

check also running example-  http://codepad.org/heNhHeB4